# How to create a number changes in excel when selected from the list?

Tags: excel, vba

i have two sheets called "Stock" and "Customer" on Stock sheet i have few different list, and on sheet Customer i have customer name and drop list to add items from the list, to keep track of my stock how can i make it so when i click something from the list the number in stock decreases, automatically? I have included same images so its easier to understand.
**Stock sheet**

[image: Stock sheet]

**Customer sheet**

[image: Customer sheet]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

I have looked online but could not find anything that i need ;(

Comment: sum the total sold on the customer sheet then subtract it from the stock sheet.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). 
Please provide details on the code you attempted, and explain on the specific issues you encountered.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.